# How to add ground to DC circuit?

Tags: dc, ground, grounding

I'm just a dabbler in electronic circuits and I'm really still kind of a noob. I am working on a project called the "Atari Punk Console" (Originally known as the "Stepped Tone Generator") but there are some parts of the wiring schematic that I don't understand, specifically the parts with the ground symbol.

Here is the schematic:
[image]

See those two ground symbols? I don't understand how to properly connect the circuit to ground at these points. How can I do this and be sure that I did it properly. I don't understand grounding at all so any pointers or clarification is also welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Two grounds are the same ground. Connect them with wire.

Comment: Just connect them to each other? Or connect them both to something else? I don't understand why if I can just connect them together, they wouldn't just draw the connection in the schematic. Why did they put a symbol for ground there instead of just a line connecting them?

Comment: More generally, connect _all_ ground symbols in the same drawing to the same wire.  That symbol means "reference ground" (Whenever someone talks about measuring the voltage _at_ some point in the circuit, they mean, the voltage _between_ that point and reference ground.  The voltage _at_ reference ground is always 0 by definition.)  It is not the same thing as "protective earth" which has a different symbol.

Comment: In more complex circuits, there will often be a _lot_ of things connected to ground.  It makes the drawing a lot cleaner if those connections aren't all connected to each other with inked lines.

Comment: Se the very recent [related question](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/162564/what-does-this-strange-symbol-refer-to).

Comment: The ground is also the reference for the output signal. If you connect the "-4dB Line Output" to the center of an RCA jack, the outside of the jack should also be connected to ground.

Comment: Highly related: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/117892/different-grounds , http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/237439/where-do-these-grounding-wires-go

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What isn't shown on your schematic is that the negative terminal of the 9 volt supply is connected to all of the other ground symbols, which are all connected together.

Answer (score 8):

"Ground" in this context doesn't mean "the earth" or "the floor" or anything like that - it is merely a virtual reference point.  In your case it is the negative connection of your battery or power supply.

All those ground symbols are just a shortcut instead of showing the wires connecting those points to your battery.  Just wire them all together and connect to -.